# Bound angle between vectors on n-simplex

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to bound from above (tight as I can find) the angle between two vectors ($\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y} $) on the standard n-simplex in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ ($\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_k = 1$, $x_k\geq0$ , and the same for $y_k$), given that distance between them is less than a constant $\epsilon $ (i.e $\| \boldsymbol{x} -\boldsymbol{y}\| \leq \epsilon)$.

My try so far:

In general, the angle between vectors is:
\begin{align} 
\theta = \arccos \frac{\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y}{\left\| \mathbf x \right\| \, \left\| \mathbf y \right\|}
\end{align}

and on the stranded simplex it satisfies $ 0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$, since the inner proudct in non-negative for vectors on the stranded simplex.

$arccos$ is monotonic decreasing, so in order to bound (tightly) the angle, it suffice to bound from below the following function:\begin{align} 
\frac{\mathbf x \cdot \mathbf y}{\left\| \mathbf x \right\| \, \left\| \mathbf y \right\|}
\end{align}

under the constraints that $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are on the simplex, and the distance between them is at most $\epsilon$.

I am not sure how to do it, or how to procced from here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you think about it geometrically, the maximum possible angle will occur at the very center of the simplex, where the $x_k$ and $y_k$ are all almost identical in value.  $\bf x - y$ is nearly perpendicular to $x$ ("nearly" because both can't be exactly in the center and still maximize the angle between them), so the distance $\epsilon$ can all go to increasing the angle, rather than some going to increasing or decreasing the radius as elsewhere on the simplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up on my comment, suppose both $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ are equally distant from the centerpoint $\bf c$ on opposite sides. So the distance from $\bf c$ to each is $\epsilon/2$. The hypersphere of radius $\|\mathbf c\| = \sqrt{1/n}$ about the origin is tangent to the simplex at $\bf c$, so the line connecting $\mathbf x, \mathbf c$, and $\bf y$ is perpendicular to the radius through $\bf c$. A little trigonometry shows the angle between $\bf c$ and $\bf x$ is $$\tan^{-1}\frac {\|x - c\|}{\|c\|} = \tan^{-1}\frac {\dfrac \epsilon 2}{\sqrt{\dfrac 1n}} = \tan^{-1}\frac {\epsilon\sqrt n}2$$
And the same for $\bf y$. Therefore the angle between $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ will be twice this:

$$2\tan^{-1}\frac {\epsilon\sqrt n}2$$

I'm pretty sure (but haven't checked) that this angle is the maximum possible.

To check it, you can use Lagrange multipliers to minimize $\bf x \cdot y$ with respect to the constraints that they lie on the simplex.